# What makes the omission of "that" in this sentence possible?

Tags: conjunctions, so

Below is an example sentence from the entry for the verb "alter" in Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary.( <= Is this a correct sentence? I am not confident with this. Excuse me for an irrelevant additional question.)

> He had altered so much I scarcely recognized him.

I have been taught that **"that"** is omitted between **"so much"** and **"I"** in the sentence.

What makes it happen or what makes it possible to happen?
I would like to get an answer focused on the reason of it.

Any personal opinions are also greatly helpful to me.
I will appreciate any explanations from you.
Thank you.

Comment: It's called a [reduced relative clause](http://www.eslgold.com/grammar/reduced_relative_clauses.html).

Comment: It is possible because a lot of English speakers do it. [It's as simple as that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJ8KIzkCAto).

Comment: @stangdon I don't think there is a relative clause. I saw the webpage you linked thoroughly and I don't think here "that" is a relative pronoun.

Comment: **That** can be employed as: a pronoun, adjective, adverb, and conjunction. Only when used as a conjunction (as in your case), sometimes it is possible to omit it. Please have a thorough look of its dictionary definitions and you'll certainly be able to get it.

Comment: @LucianSava I know that there reads as you say. I already so many times looked at it thoroughly. What I am asking is the reason for it. I believe everything has its own cause or reason.

Comment: When some constructions are often used they tend to change because of usage due to efficiency or laziness. Small words like "that" tend to drop out if there is no loss of understanding.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for the precious answering. :) But, is "because of usage due to efficiency or laziness" a correct expression? I can't understand the structure well.

Comment: "because of usage due *(either)* to efficiency or *(to)* laziness" has construction of "either...or" and parallel construction in "to... or to..." which both constructions are then contracted (due to efficiency).

Comment: @Peter Thank you for the answer. It wass very helpful to me. :) But can I ask you another question? I am sorry to keep asking questions about your comment, but would you also explain about the "which both constructions are then contracted" part? At first I thought it is a relative clause seeing "which", but it doesn't make sense as a relative clause.

Answer (score 1):

> I scarcely recognized him, he had changed so much.
>
> He had changed so much, I scarcely recognized him.

In the first sentence, there is an implicit **because**, by which I mean that "he had changed so much" is offered as the *cause* or *reason*. In the second sentence, there is an implicit **therefore**; "I scarcely recognized him" is presented as the *result*.   We can infer the causal relationship from the sequence of clauses and do not require explicit conjunctions (e.g. **because**, **therefore**) .

The sentences could be said like this:

> He had changed so much *that* I scarcely recognized him.
>
> I scarcely recognized him *for that* he had changed so much.

*that* and *for that* introducing result-clause and cause-clause, respectively, although **for that** meaning 'because' has largely fallen out of use during the last 150-200 years or so, and was already something of an archaism in the 19th century.

However, I don't believe we could say that in the first set of examples the particular conjunctions **that** and **for that** have been omitted. All we can say is that the causal relationship is expressed without a conjunction.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider that example in a different light; turn it right round.

*I scarcely recognized him; he had altered so much.*

Exactly how is that re-phrasing wrong? Since in my view that is by no means wrong, I feel wholly happy with dropping *that* from your original.